# Vue v-model does not work with individual index of array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I have a row of inputs: a checkbox and a dropdown button.

Then, there is another button to add a new row of inputs.

The checkbox, when checked would disable the dropdown and make it non-required.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <tr v-for="(item, i) of timesheet.items" :key="i">
    <div>
        <td>
            <input 
                type= "checkbox"
                v-model="checked"
                id= "{{ 'disable' + i }}" 
                v-on:click= "disable(i)"
            >
        </td>
        <td>
            <select2 
                :id="'project_id-' + i" 
                v-bind:class="{
                    'is-invalid': item.project_id.$error,
                    'is-valid':
                    item.project_id.$dirty &&
                    !item.project_id.$error,
                }"
            >
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option v-for="(project) in projects" 
                    :selected="project.id == timesheet.project_id" 
                    :key="project.id" 
                    :value="project.id">{{ project.name }}</option>
            </select2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button 
                type="button" 
                class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
                @click="itemCount++"
            >Add Row
            </button>
        </td>
    </div>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    import { required, minLength } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                checked: false,
                timesheet: { items: [{ project_id: "" }] },
            }
        },
        validations() {
            if (!this.checked) {
                return{
                    itemCount: 1,
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { project_id: { required }}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                return{
                    timesheet: {
                        items: {
                            required,
                            minLength: minLength(1),
                            $each: { project_id: {} }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        },
        watch: {
            itemCount(value, oldValue) {
                if (value > oldValue) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < value - oldValue; i++) {
                        this.timesheet.items.push({
                            project_id: "",
                            checked: false,
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    this.timesheet.items.splice(value);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {            
            disable(index){
                const check = 
                        document.getElementById('project_id-' + index).disabled
                $('#project_id-' + index).attr('disabled', !check);
            }
        },        
    }
</script>
```

The first checkbox does the work as intended but, whenever another row is added, the new one is always pre-checked and is behaving the exact opposite of the first.

So, my question is how do I fix my v-model?

Comment: Please show the code where row elements are added. Also, where are `i` and `itemsCount` defined? The checkbox has `id="disable"`, is this a typo? Shouldn't it be dynamic just like `'project_id-'+i`?

Comment: @Mythos thank you for your respose. I have got those corrected, Sir.

Comment: Should I amend my ````v-model```` too, Sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a couple of problems I see with your code.

First, the checkbox has `id= "{{ 'disable' + i }}"`, using interpolation in attributes is not allowed, you should use `:id="'disable' + i"`.

Second, I still don't understand where you've defined `itemsCount`, I'll assume its under `data`.

Third, you're using the same v-model for all checkboxes, which is your `checked` model under `data`. So clicking any checkbox will change `checked` and this change will be updated in other checkboxes as well. Which is why all your checkboxes behave in sync.

Fourth, you've defined `timesheet: { items: [{ project_id: "" }] }`, so `item` only contains `project_id` property. But later when you add items you use `this.timesheet.items.push({ project_id: "", checked: false })`, which tells me you're trying to have the `checked` property for each `item`, which you meant to use for each checkbox. Well, then you have the right idea.

What you need to do is add a `checked` property to `items` in `data`, and use this as v-model for your checkboxes.

```js
  data() {
    return {
      itemCount: 1,
      timesheet: { items: [{ project_id: "", checked: false }] },
    };
  },
```

```html
<input
  type="checkbox"
  v-model="item.checked"
  :id="'disable' + i"
  v-on:click="disable(i)"
/>
```

Comment: still, the ``validation()`` triggers some console warning: ``[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: item is not defined"``

Comment: How do I put the correct syntax of ``!this.checked`` as the condition of the ``if else`` part, Sir?

Comment: I've tried these: ``!item.checked``, ``!timesheet.item.checked``, ``!this.item.checked`` and ``!this.timesheet.item.checked``, but they none of them worked.

Comment: That's a `vuelidate` related question. You should try looking it up in vuelidate docs (look for `requiredIf`) or ask another question if you don't find anything, I'll be glad to answer.

Comment: Noted that, thank you for your kind assistance, Sir @Mythos

Comment: @user16780927 Please accept my answer as correct if it helped you.